# Juniper IS-IS levels hierarchy configuration

Tags: juniper, is-is

Can someone please tell me what is the interface ge-2/1/0.0 IS-IS level after we have applied this config?

Does Juniper takes both commands?

- level 2 disable at the interface level
- level 1 disable at the protocol level

Or just one of them?

```
protocols { 
        isis {
                level 1 { 
                          disable; 
                        } 
                interface ge-2/1/0.0 { 
                                        level 2 { 
                                                  disable; 
                                                }
                                      } 

                interface ge-2/2/0.0;
                interface lo0.0;
             }
      }
```

From my understanding I believe that the interface ge-2/1/0.0 will have both level 1 and level 2 disabled, but I am not sure.

Thank you

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I was correct.

The interface ge-2/1/0.0 will have both level 1 and level 2 disabled.

I have just seen this question on the Junos Genius APP for Android.

Comment: I just tried configuring this on a pair of srx240's running Junos 12.1X44 both level one and two are disabled. Not what I'd expected, but it is correct